# Monotonicity of $f(x) =\sin(\ln(x))-\cos(\ln(x))$

Tags: derivatives

Find the interval in which $f(x) =\sin(\ln(x))-\cos(\ln(x))$ is increasing. 
After differentiating we get $$f'(x) = \frac{\cos\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x} +\frac{\sin\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x}$$
Now how do we analyze this expression?

Comment: Note the function is undefined for $x=0$, for $x=1$ the expression for the derivative is equal to 1, and since sine and cosine never reach values greater than 1, the expression for the derivative will continue to decrease for larger values of $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:  Try applying the identity $\cos \theta + \sin \theta = \sqrt{2} \sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4} )$ to the derivative, or $\sin \theta - \cos \theta = \sqrt{2} \sin(\theta - \frac{\pi}{4})$ to the original function.

Answer (score 3):

Just to rewrite your derivative in better latex
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sin(\ln(x))-\cos(\ln(x))\Big)=\frac{\cos(\ln(x))}{x}+\frac{\sin(\ln(x))}{x}.
\end{equation}
We want the interval in which the function is increasing, so we want the derivative to be positive
\begin{equation}
\frac{\cos(\ln(x))}{x}+\frac{\sin(\ln(x))}{x}>0.
\end{equation}
The variable x must be greater than zero for the log to be defined, so we get
\begin{equation}
\cos(\ln(x))+\sin(\ln(x))>0.
\end{equation}
To find the critical points, set the two terms equal
\begin{equation}
\cos(\ln(x))=-\sin(\ln(x)) \rightarrow \tan(\ln(x))=-1.
\end{equation}
This equality is satisfied for 
\begin{equation}
\ln(x)=-\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi \rightarrow x=e^{-\pi/4+n\pi}.
\end{equation}
So the infinite number of intervals for which your function is increasing are seperated by the points $e^{-\pi/4+n\pi}$ for any integer $n$.  To see which one is increasing consider $x=1$ which is between the value $n=-1$ and $n=0$.  For this value the derivative is $1$ and so it is increasing.  The other intervals alternate between decreasing and increasing.

Comment: Really nicely done. What about cos(ln(x))=0  @teddy ?

Comment: Thanks, in that case you can also find the answer to cos(y)=0, which is $y=\pi/2+n\pi$, to find the answers $x=e^{\pi/2+n\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

I like Michael Seifer's hint above.  It is a useful trick to have in your kit.

However, picking up where you left off.

$\frac{(\cos(\ln(x)))}{x} +\frac{(\sin(\ln(x)))}{x}>0$

$\ln x$ is not defined when $x \le 0$

$\cos(\ln(x)) +\sin(\ln(x))>0\\
\cos(\ln(x)) > - \sin(\ln(x))\\
\ln x \in (-\frac {\pi}{4} + 2n\pi, \frac {3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi)\\
x \in (e^{-\frac {\pi}{4} + 2n\pi}, e^{\frac {3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi})$

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\frac{\sin \log x+\cos \log x}{x}$$

$\log x$ is an increasing function. Substitute $u=\log x$. Denominator is positive because $x$ is argument of logarithm.

$\sin u + \cos u > 0\to \sin u > - \cos u$

$\sin u = -\cos u$ when $\tan u=-1$ when $u=\dfrac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi,\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$

therefore $\sin u > - \cos u$ for

$2k\pi<u<\dfrac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi\lor \dfrac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi<u<2(k+1)\pi$

that is

$2k\pi<\log x<\dfrac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi\lor \dfrac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi<\log x<2(k+1)\pi$

and finally

$e^{2k\pi}< x<e^{\frac{3\pi}{4}+2k\pi}\lor e^{\frac{5\pi}{4}+2k\pi}<x<e^{2(k+1)\pi}$

these intervals are very huge, for instance for $k=3$ the derivative is positive in

$(1.5\times 10^8,1.62009\times 10^9)\cup (7.79343\times 10^9,8.22263\times 10^{10})$

and graph is pretty weird, too

Hope this helps

**edit**

$f''(x)=-\dfrac{2 \sin (\log (x))}{x^2}$

Thus $x=e^{2 \pi  k}$ are inflexion points because $f''(x)=0$

$x=e^{2 \pi  k+\frac{3 \pi }{4}}$ are maxima because $f''(x)<0$

$x=e^{2 \pi  k+\frac{5 \pi }{4}}$ are minima

as $k\to -\infty$ maxima and minima oscillate in intervals exponentially smaller and smaller when $x\to 0^+$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the function $g(x)=\sin x-\cos x$ instead (see Seifert's answer). After that, assume that
$$e^a\le t<t'\le e^b$$
Then $ a\le\ln t<\ln t'\le b$. Therefore, if $g$ is increasing in $[a,b]$, we have $f(t)<f(t')$. Same reasoning if $g$ is decreasing in the interval.

Thus, $f$ is (in)(de)creasing in $[e^a,e^b]$ if and only if $g$ is (in)(de)creasing in $[a,b]$.